# IOS/Android Push notifications

Tags: android, ios, push

I am planning some app as a part of our product. One part of the app will be to receive push messages.

Sometimes it's months between uses of the app and, by experience with other apps I've used, it seems like there is some timeout. If you don't use the app in a while, it will stop receiving push notifications.

So, does iOS/Android push notification subscriptions expire if the app is not used in a while? or is this something the app developer has done in their own code?

If there is some limitations in iOS/Andoid, what is it and are there some way to avoid this as it's important that push notifications will arrive, even when the app hasn't been used for months.

Comment: This probably depends on the terms of service for the individual push notification service providers (i.e. Google and Apple). Therefore, this is [more of a customer support question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) for them than a software engineering concepts question for us.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS there is no time limit imposed by Apple. Note that any push notifications will lead to a notification shown on the screen (under control of the app), so it wouldn’t matter whether the app is run or not. Apple sends the notification to the users phone, Apple doesn’t know whether the use reacts to it or not.